# How to handle Kafka consumer exception with batch mode

Tags: apache-kafka

I used batch mode and manual ack to consume records, and I created a class to implement KafkaListenerErrorHandler so that can handle exception. It seems that when a runtime exception happened, the broker did not receive ack which means when I restarted the application, those values are consumed again.

My expectation is that when an exception happens, don't affect other values so that when the application restarts, previous values will not be consumed again. Currently, it seems that manual ack is not executed even though we have an error handler. Besides using try-catch to catch an exception and skip to next value. Are there any other ways to handle this kind of situation.

Comment: For example, producer sends 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 to broker in order, and consumer use batch mode to consume records. when value is 5 and 7, I throw a runtime exception. My expectation is that don't let runtime exception affect the whole records.